# expandablelistview getchildview display incorrectly

Tags: expandablelistview, fill-parent

I'm new to android, I'm now trying to use ExpandableListView to list firstly work types in group level then work items in child level. But it's very strange that layout fill_parent not work in getChildView method, it just act like wrap_content, and also relevant textviews' height become 0 when I Log them regardness of what I set in layout and thus all textview looks gone unless I manually set text size in code. Most strangest thing is only child view has the problem, group level works fine where I do not need to set any textsize or height.

Below are some pieces of the code, could you please help me find out what's the matter? Thank you very very much!!

1. Activity

> ```
> public class WorkListActivity extends Activity implements
>     ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener {
> private ExpandableListView elv;
> List<WorkTypeBean> worktypes = null;
> ExpandableAdapter viewAdapter;
> WorkTypeBean worktypeBean = null;
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.work_items);
>     elv = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.workList_ev);
>     elv.setOnGroupClickListener(this);
>     getWorkTypes();  //get all work types user can visit from server
> }
> @Override
> public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
>         int groupPosition, long id) {
>     if (!parent.isGroupExpanded(groupPosition)){
>         getWorkItems(groupPosition);  
>         //fetch work items from server only when specific group clicked
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> class ExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
>     @Override
>     public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
>             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>         ViewHolder holder;
>         if (convertView==null){
>             LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
>                     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>             convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(
>                     R.layout.work_items_c, null);
>             holder = new ViewHolder();
>             holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_work_item_title);
>             holder.tv2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_work_item_applier);
>             holder.iv1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_work_item_hl);
>             convertView.setTag(holder);
>         }else{
>             holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
>         }
>         convertView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
>         WorkTypeBean typeBean = worktypes.get(groupPosition);
>         if (typeBean==null){
>             return convertView;
>         }
>         WorkItemBean workitem = typeBean.getItem(childPosition);
>         if (workitem==null){
>             return convertView;
>         }
>         String title = workitem.getTitle();
>         String applier = workitem.getApplier();
>         String postdate = workitem.getArriveTime();
>         int waitdays = Integer.parseInt(workitem.getWaitDays());
>         holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
>         holder.tv1.setText(title);
>         holder.tv1.setTextSize(15);
>         holder.tv2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
>         holder.tv2.setTextSize(10);
>         //if not set, tv2 remains original text "loading..." from work_item_c.xml
>         holder.tv2.setText(applier+" ("+postdate+")");
>         if (waitdays > 2){
>             holder.iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.wl_urgent);
>         }else{
>             holder.iv1.setImageResource(R.drawable.wl_normal);
>         }
>         return convertView;
>     }
>     @Override
>     public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
>             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
>         ViewHolder holder;
> if (convertView == null) {
> LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext()
> .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
> convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.work_items_h, null);
>             holder = new ViewHolder();
>             holder.tv1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_worktype);
>             holder.iv1 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_worktype_counter);
>             convertView.setTag(holder);
>         }else{
>             holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
> }
>         WorkTypeBean worktype = worktypes.get(groupPosition);
>         if (worktype==null){
>             return convertView;
>         }
>         holder.tv1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
>         holder.tv1.setText(worktype.getTitle());
>         return convertView;    
>     }
>     //... some other code 
>     }
>     }
> ```

1. group level layout: work_items_h.xml  //works correctly

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> ```
>
> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>     <RelativeLayout
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="match_parent" >
>
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/tv_worktype"
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
>             android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
>             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/iv_worktype_counter"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
>             android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
>
>     </RelativeLayout>
>
> </LinearLayout>
>      </LinearLayout>
> ```

1. child level layout: work_items_c.xml //fill_parent not work, neither textview height

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> ```
>
> ```
>     <LinearLayout
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
>
>         <ImageView
>             android:id="@+id/iv_work_item_hl"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:src="@drawable/wl_normal" />
>
>         <LinearLayout
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>             android:orientation="vertical" >
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/tv_work_item_title"
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:text="loading..."
>                 android:textSize="15dp" />
>             <!--tried android:layout_height="fill_parent" but not work-->
>
>             <TextView
>                 android:id="@+id/tv_work_item_applier"
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>                 android:gravity="right"
>                 android:text="loading..."
>                 android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
>                 android:textSize="10dp" />
>
>         </LinearLayout>
>
>     </LinearLayout>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Just override layout from some others and it's now correct. 
Here are my new layouts:

1. work_item_h.xml

> ```
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tv_worktype"
>         android:layout_width="259dp"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="left|center"
>         android:paddingBottom="10px"
>         android:paddingLeft="40px"
>         android:paddingTop="10px"
>         android:textColor="#ff0000"
>         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
>         android:textSize="20.0px" />
>
>     <ImageView
>         android:id="@+id/iv_worktype_counter"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="right|center"
>         android:src="@drawable/counter" />
>
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

1. work_item_c.xml

> ```
> <ImageView
>     android:id="@+id/iv_work_item_hl"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="2.0px"
>     android:layout_marginLeft="10.0px"
>     android:layout_marginTop="10.0px"
>     android:paddingTop="6.0px" />
>
> <LinearLayout
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_marginBottom="2.0px"
>     android:baselineAligned="@+id/iv_work_item_hl"
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:paddingTop="2.0px" >
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tv_work_item_title"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="left|center"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10.0px"
>         android:textColor="#ff000000"
>         android:textSize="20.0px" />
>
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/tv_work_item_applier"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="left|center"
>         android:layout_marginLeft="10.0px"
>         android:textColor="#ff838383"
>         android:textSize="13.0px" />
> </LinearLayout>
> ```

But I still don't know what's the problem on my previous layout, it showed correctly in my eclipse layout designer. Anyway, I'm glad to see it works finally. Thanks anyone..., seems no one care about my question, then thank myself, thank God:)

Regards,
Jeff